# Inputbox looks different in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, mozilla, inputbox

see `http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2009/09/fancy-contact-form/demo.php`

it is same contact form that i integrated in my website. it works perfect except input `text boxes` WIDTH. how could make it same as looks in  Mozilla Firefox. Any idea, suggestion for it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the styles are set differently in both browsers (different inline style and class attribute values)

Comment: can u point what code it is being used.. here is source code  `http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2009/09/fancy-contact-form/demo.zip`